# 1980s robot cartoon. A boy, girl and a baby robot, they were red bodied with white heads

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

Does anyone remember an obscure short lived cartoon in the 1980s. I remember it had 3 characters, boy, girl and a baby robot. Red bodies, white head, yellow belts and yellow and blue shoes. They made toys of them and when you used batteries they played the theme song.

Comment: You seem to know a lot of the details about the style, can you tell us if it was Dark or Bright, Anime or American or something else. Was the animation cheap or clean? Was there any shading or was everything flat-painted. Were the backgrounds minimal or detailed?

Comment: Yes, please update this question.  What was the accent/language used?  Where were you living?

Comment: Likely a duplicate of this; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/194772/20774

Comment: @Valorum Except the OP specifically mentions shoe and belt colour. The Telebugs don't have shoes or belts. I feel like Telebugs is not the right answer.

Answer (score 7):

[*Telebugs*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telebugs) (aka *The Gigglebytes*) seems awfully close, despite only one red-bodied bot:

[image]

> The Telebugs were a hi-tech trio of merry monitored robots created by 
>       absent-minded Professor Brainstrain - or indeed, 'Bwainstwain' owing
>       to his unfortunate lisp. Theses robots were 'Pwogwammed to help people
>       in twouble', but more specifically to combat the new threat of computerized 
>       villains and advanced adversaries springing up around the country.
>
> The Telebugs' leader was a white-shelled droid called Chip. He was 
>       a calculation robot, able to process data and statistics at a phenomenal
>       rate. Samantha was the yellow one. She was a hi-tech monitor and 
>       tracking device. Her bow-tie was actually a spinning radar. Then there
>       was Bug, the red robot programmed to acquire video footage and pictures.
>       Bug came with a sidekick called Mic, a mobile independent camera.

And yes, [there were toys](http://www.vectis.co.uk/Page/ViewLot.aspx?LotId=413894&Section=0&all=1).

[image: Toys image]

Comment: There's *always* toys.

Answer (score 2):

Robot Man. Tried to post a pix. Not sure if it worked

[image]

Comment: You should [edit] this to give a description of how it matches the description in the question as well as the image. Also an actual image rather than a screenshot of search results would be a lot better.

Comment: There's a little more info from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-BY9ZhIpFNg. I never knew about his background or the cartoon... I remember the newspaper strip, very vaguely.

Answer (score 1):

Following up with an expanded version of [t.k.'s answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/231914/23243):

This may be the cartoon adaptation of the [Robotman](http://www.toonopedia.com/robotman.htm) character, *[Robotman & Friends](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-BY9ZhIpFNg)*. Robotman was perhaps better known for his newspaper comic-strip, which was later renamed after support character [*Monty*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_(comic_strip)).

> In 1984, Peter Shelley recorded an album (apparently released in 1985) called "Robotman and Friends, Straight From The Heart".  This album was the soundtrack to the animated cartoon above.  The soundtrack included keyboard work by John Woloschuk.  It was also co-produced by John Woloschuk.  One of the songs, though, goes back to 1977. It appears that Mr. Shelly was working on this concept for a while.
>
> In 1985, United Feature Syndicate asked Jim Meddick to create a comic strip based around the Robotman character.  The visual appearance of Robotman was about all that Meddick kept from the original Robotman. Over the years, the strip went through some changes. Eventually it was renamed "Robotman and Monty".  Later, Robotman was phased out and the strip was again renamed, this time to just "Monty". http://www.klaatu.org/Robotman-records.html

### Cartoon opening

The appearance is not quite the same as you remember, with Robotman and Oops being in red and yellow, Stellar being in white and pink, and there was also Lint, a white fuzzy humanoid creature.

[image: Title Image with Robotman, Stellar, Oops, and Lint]

And indeed, there were toy dolls released of the characters that would play music.

[image: Image of Stellar, Robotman, and Oops dolls] [image: Image of Lint doll]

More [merchandise](http://ignatz.brinkster.net/rman/ritems.html) can be found on Jim Meddick's site.

Comment: TIL you can paste images saved to the clipboard as well as URLs pointing at pictures.