# 80s Cartoons with three robots with "screen" heads one white, one yellow and one red

Tags: story-identification, robots, cartoon

I remember watching a cartoon, in the late '80s, for which I can't remember the name. The cartoon was surely American, had a light tone and was clearly aimed at kids.

It featured three robots as protagonists, that had no legs, could float/fly and that had a kind of TV screen as a head (the screen displayed their face). They were different colours, white, red and yellow, and lived together with the scientist who had built them and a cat.

Usually the episodes revolved about them fighting against different villains, among which there was even a robot similar to them.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is [*The Telebugs*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Telebugs) (1986-7)

> The Telebugs is a British cartoon from the 1980s about the adventures of three robots with televisions for heads.
>
> The Telebugs were a hi-tech trio of merry monitored robots created by absent-minded Professor Brainstrain. These robots were, in the professor's own words, '*Pwogwammed to help people in twouble*', but more specifically to combat the new threat of computerized villains and advanced adversaries springing up around the country.
>
> <sub><sup>[TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WesternAnimation/TheTelebugs)</sup></sub>

Comment: You've beaten me to a second there.

Comment: It is exactly this one! Thank you a lot!

Comment: @McTroopers - [Always a pleasure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ)

Comment: Not accepted, but also the answer at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28279/1980s-robot-cartoon-a-boy-girl-and-a-baby-robot-they-were-red-bodied-with-whi/28281#28281